# How to return callback node.js?

Tags: javascript, async-await, callback

```js
var iwconfig = require("wireless-tools/iwconfig");
let api = {};

api.getStatusWifi = function () {
  iwconfig.status(function (err, status) {
    console.log(status);
  });
  // return status ???????????
};

module.exports = api;
```

how can I pass the "status callback" return to the "getStatusWifi"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the "api.getStatusWifi =" part inside the function where the status variable is available.

```
var iwconfig = require("wireless-tools/iwconfig");
let api = {};

 iwconfig.status(function (err, status) {
    api.getStatusWifi = function () {
     return status;
    };
 });
  
module.exports = api;
```